# Ajax the button is not changing until refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

If I click the like or unlike button it sends the data and works as expected but the problem is it doesn't change the button instantly when you click until I refresh the page. eg. when I click like button it should change to unlike,  I don't see errors in console, I have seen some questions similar to this but they haven't solved my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Javascript

```
function addToFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/product/like/${productid}`,
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
console.log($('#addfavourites' + productid));
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).show();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});

}

   // Unlike product
function deleteFromFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `product/${productid}/unlike`,
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
console.log($('#addfavourites' + productid));
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).show();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});
}
```

Blade File

```
 @if($product->isLiked)
 <div id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}"onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{   Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
 @else
<div id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
@endif
```

Comment: because you need to update your button in the `success` function

Comment: how do I update? @Joseph

Comment: try to add `id` for your button and from your `success` function write this `let data = $('#like_btn').text();` `data = (data === 'like')? 'unlike' : 'like';`  `$('like_btn').text(data)`

Comment: Where do I put the `id` and also should I put that code above the success function or under? @Joseph

Comment: ofcourse it's not changing, the main problem is that you use if else on entire div section and separate it as different div, you should just display:none css attribute and use hide() and show() on success callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should update the button in your success function of the ajax call
Since the condition is written in blade template, it will not trigger until you refresh the page so in order to change the button write the code in success function.

Try changing your code to something like this

```
<div style="display: {{$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}} id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}"onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{   Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
<div style=" display: {{!$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}} id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
```

And then inside your success function do following

After liking do

```
$('#addfavourites'+productId).hide();
$('#deletefavourite'+productId).show();
```

After unliking call

```
$('#deletefavourite'+productId).hide();
$('#addfavourites'+productId).show();
```

Not tested this is just an idea for you.